# Firebase, Next-js showing TypeError on page reload

Tags: firebase, next.js

Chats.js

```
function Chat() {
  const [emails, setEmails] = useState([]);
  const userChatRef = db.collection("users").where("email", "==", auth.currentUser.email);
  const [chatSnapshot] = useCollection(userChatRef);
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("users").get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        setEmails(oldmails => [...oldmails, doc.data().email]);
      });
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="user-container">
      <div className="user-nav">
        <Image src={auth.currentUser.photoURL} width={35} height={35} />
      </div>
      <div className="chats">
        {chatSnapshot?.docs[0]?.data()?.chats.map((chat) => {
          return <EachChat key={chat.email} chat={chat} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Chat;
```

EachChat.js

```
function EachChat({ chat }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const recipientChatRef = db.collection("users").where("email", "==", chat.email);
  const [recipientSnapshot] = useCollection(recipientChatRef);
  const imageUrl = recipientSnapshot?.docs[0]?.data()?.image;
  const redirectChat = () => {
    router.push(`/chat/${chat.uid}`);
  };
  return (
    <div className="d-flex each-chat" onClick={redirectChat}>
      <Image src={imageUrl} width={35} height={35} />
      <div>{chat.email}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default EachChat;
```

[uid].js

```
function ChatComp() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Chat />
      <h1>This is a Chat</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
export default ChatComp;
```

I'm getting an error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null` from the `db.collection(...).where(...)` statement, but only when I refresh the `[uid].js` page and not when I redirect to same page. The `Chat` component works properly also after refreshing.

Also why i'm getting the error only after refreshing and not on first load?

Comment: Where does `auth.currentUser` come from?

Comment: @juliomalves Just a file I created `const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); const auth = app.auth(); export { auth };`

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring most likely because you're trying to populate your HTML prior to the information being delivered. If you wait for your data to completely load that may resolve your issue.

```
function Chat() {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [emails, setEmails] = useState([]);
  var [userChatRef, setUserChatRef] = useState()
  const [chatSnapshot] = useCollection(userChatRef);
  useEffect(() => {

  setUserChatRef(db.collection("users").where("email", "==", auth.currentUser.email));

    db.collection("users").get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        setEmails(oldmails => [...oldmails, doc.data().email]);
        setLoading(false)
      });
    });
  }, []);
  return (<>

  {loading == true ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : <div className="user-container">
      <div className="user-nav">
        <Image src={auth.currentUser.photoURL} width={35} height={35} />
      </div>
      <div className="chats">
        {chatSnapshot?.docs[0]?.data()?.chats.map((chat) => {
          return <EachChat key={chat.email} chat={chat} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>}

  </>);
}
export default Chat;
```

Comment: Sorry to say but it just reads the `email` from **`.where`** as undefined on page refresh.

Comment: What do you mean it reads the data as undefined? You mean that is what it is returning in setEmails?

Comment: `const userChatRef = db.collection("users").where("email", "==", auth.currentUser.email);` this part shows `.email` as `Cannot read property of null`

Comment: Got it.  I changed my answer to show what it may look like to wait until the value is received from the server. If this also doesn't work there may be additional loading changing to make, but its worth a try.

Comment: I did the changes but the error remains the same

Comment: I don't think `auth` has anything to do with the HTML render ?